# how to increase the login time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

hi i'm having a serious problem in my admin panel , every time i try to update,delete or insert data into database it redirect me to the login page again and that's wrong so how can i keep the user logged in , another problem is it always gives me the `"verisfy csrf token "` when i make a lot of changes and i put the `{{csrf_field()}}` in each form so what's the problem ? i tried to increase the session time to 1200 but it doesn't work so can anyone help me please ?  and that's my kernel :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

and that's my route :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
/*
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
*/
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'middleware'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
    Route::controller('about','abouttitleController');
    Route::controller('abouttitleedit','abouttitleeditController');
    Route::controller('aboutcategory','aboutcategoryController');
    Route::controller('aboutcategoryedit','aboutcategoryeditController');
    Route::controller('abouttopic','abouttopicController');
    Route::controller('abouttopicedit','abouttopiceditController');
    Route::controller('features','featuresController');
    Route::controller('featuresedit','featureseditController');
    Route::controller('contact','contactController');
    Route::controller('hirecategory','hirecategoryController');
    Route::controller('hiretitle','hiretitleController');
    Route::controller('hiretitleedit','hiretitleeditController');
    Route::controller('hirecategoryedit','hirecategoryeditController');
    Route::controller('hiretopicedit','hiretopiceditController');
    Route::controller('servicescategory','servicescategoryController');
    Route::controller('servicescategoryedit','servicescategoryeditController');
    Route::controller('servicestitle','servicestitleController');
    Route::controller('servicestitleedit','servicestitleeditController');
    Route::controller('servicessubcategory','servicessubcategoryController');
    Route::controller('servicessubedit','servicessubcategoryeditController');
    Route::controller('residentialservices','residentialController');
    Route::controller('residentialedit','residentialeditController');
    Route::controller('slider','sliderController');
    Route::controller('slideredit','slidereditController');
    Route::controller('testmonials','testmonialsController');
    Route::controller('testmonialsedit','testmonialseditController');
    Route::controller('tips','tipsController');
    Route::controller('tipsedit','tipseditController');
    Route::controller('commercialtitle','commercialtitleController');
    Route::controller('commercialtitleedit','commercialtitleeditController');
    Route::controller('commercialtopic','commercialtopicController');
    Route::controller('commercialtopicedit','commercialtopiceditController');
    Route::controller('meta','metaController');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether your route use web middle ware group, like the following

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () { 
});
```

if not please let me see your kernal file and the route file

Comment: i removed it form my routes and i will post my kernel right now

Comment: i updated my question and posted the kernel.php file

Comment: your kernal file is fine, donot remove route, make sure that the protected routes must include web middle ware in order for the session to work properly

Comment: look i made this in all my controllers could it be the error : public function __construct(){
     $this->middleware('auth');
    }

Comment: show me your route,  no it won't cause error, it means only authenticated use can access the area,

Comment: I edited your post and enclosed the routes in  `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {   });`
test it and it should work